# Knockout + Typescript + NodeJS issue HTMLElement does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js, typescript

I am not sure if I am missing something here but I have a new project with Knockout.d.ts and I have included the knockout npm package. The only issue I can see if that the d.ts is for version 2.2.3 and the knockout npm package is 3.0.0. Typescript is installed via npm as the latest version and NodeJs is 0.10.15.

Anyway that aside whenever I try to compile the project I get the error `Could not find symbol HTMLElement`. Which I guess makes sense as there is no HTML element notion in nodeJS however I was wondering how I am meant to get around this?

I have tried adding a `declare var HTMLElement: any` however that didn't seem to work as I guess it sees it as a variable not a type, and I dont want to have to make my own custom HTML/Node/Element/Document based interfaces to satisfy the dependencies...

So am I doing something wrong or is there some other dependency that is missing here? As there is not much information available online to do with this.

Comment: Are you trying to use knockout on server side?

Comment: @Carlos487 Yes I am, I believe 3.0.0 added support for this, and having an npm package for it implies it is supported.

Comment: I think the npm packages are also used to add a dependency to a front end project. It's not warranty that could work with node. But I've worked with knockout v2  maybe in v3 is posible.

Comment: I am happy to use version 2 of knockout if it works with nodejs, I am basically sharing some client side code with a server side nodejs project as a prototype (the models shared are pojos with knockout validation rules applied). Do you have a link to an example of anything which shows knockout working with nodejs?

Comment: Maybe you should look to backbone it has an mvc architecture, and sorry if I did'n explain I've worked with v2 but only in front end project, I don't think it will work with node because node use binding in their view model which are tied to a interface.

Comment: Also there ase some Knockout methods that could export JS object from the model, maybe that would help you so in the server side you have plain pojo's

Comment: Don't like Backbone, knockout is perfect and have an entire framework and project written with it across browser and mobile platforms (cordova/phonegap). It is just my web services which the clients call is in c# and I wanted to reduce code duplication and just convert that to typescript too

Answer (score 1):

HTMLElement is defined in lib.d.ts. Seems like a choppy install. Try reinstalling TypeScript and make sure you are **not** using the --nolib compiler flag

Comment: I thought this may be the case, but it all seems to be working fine, installed with `npm install -g typescript` and if I do `tsc -v` it gives me the normal 0.9.1.1 blurb with command usage, I am just calling tsc directly with the declarations flag and the output file supplied, then a list of other files. A few of which reference the knockout.d.ts file.